# How to configure nginx ingress resource timeout parameters

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

So here is my problem, I want to set up in Kubernetes ingress resource 3 timeout parameters. Described method in the Kubernetes docs is to use either ingress resource annotations or ConfigMap. In the example below I am trying with annotations but for unknown reason the change is not taking effect.

```
nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: 10s
nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: 10s
nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: 10s
```

I am setting those parameters in my ingress resource deffinition:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-foobar-ingress
  namespace: foobar
  annotations:
    nginx.org/proxy-send-timeout: "10s"
    nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "10s"
    nginx.org/proxy-read-timeout: "10s"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: foobar.foo.bar
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: foobar-svc
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
```

The other way to set up nginx configurations is through a ConfigMap, but I do not want to do it globally so I need to use annotations to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure these are the correct annotations? Have a look at [ingress/annotations/proxy/main.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/core/pkg/ingress/annotations/proxy/main.go), where the following constants are defined:

```
connect      = "ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout"
send         = "ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout"
read         = "ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout"
```

Comment: Today i have tried it with ingress.kubernetes.io but i had to get rid of the "s" and set it like "ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: 10"

Comment: Some docs: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md#custom-timeouts
The timeout is in seconds and is a number, not 60s for example. It must be ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout : 60